# Euler Multiplicator O.D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the O.D.E $y'=-\frac { { y }^{ 3 }+{ 3x }^{ 2 }y+6xy }{ 3({ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }) } $ which is not exact. I want to find a Euler Multiplicator which only depends on x.

so i bring it in the form ${ (y }^{ 3 }-{ 3x }^{ 2 }y-6xy)dx+3({ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 })dy=0$

and now using the recipe for finding the Multiplicator M:
$\frac { M' }{ M } =\frac { { g }_{ y }-{ h }_{ x } }{ h } =\frac { ({ 3y }^{ 2 }-{ 3x }^{ 2 }-6x)-(6x) }{ 3({ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }) } $

with $g(x,y)={ (y }^{ 3 }-{ 3x }^{ 2 }y-6xy)\\ h(x,y)=3({ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 })$

To procced with the recipe The R.H.S needs to depend only on x thats where im stuck since it depends on x and y hence disagreeing with the definiton/recipe, what can i do to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: set $$y(x)=xu(x)$$ to solve the equation
$$xu'+u=\frac{-x^3u^3-3x^3u-6x^2u}{3(x^2+x^2u)}$$
$$u'=-\frac{(3x+3u^2+xu+9)u}{3x(u^2+1)}$$
$$\frac{3u'(u^2+1)}{(u^2+3)u}=-\frac{x+3}{x}$$

Comment: Sorry i can't see how this brings me to my integrating factor. Since i would have to solve a hard integral with an arbitrary function in it?

Comment: Sorry have to ask again u stated a method for solving the O.D.E however im trying to use the method of finding and Integrating Factor!

Comment: you don't Need such a factor, see my post!